# Modal pop up backdrop fade in still appearing after closing the popup

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 2 popup on myscreen which is linking one to another. when i click the 2nd popup it appears and when i close the pop up, the popup content goes off, but the backdrop still remains and disables the whole page.
html:

```
<div id="license-temp" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">                  
                  <div class="get-license-popup">
                       <div class="license-heading">Get License</div> 

                       <br>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                          <div class="license-description reg">What is the duration of the usage?</div>
                          <div class="duration">
                            <select id="usage-time">
                              <option>1 Week - $0.9</option>
                              <option>1 Weeks - $2.0</option>
                              <option>1 Month - $5.0</option>
                              <option>2 Months - $10.0</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-8"><div class="license-description reg">What is the preferred return method?</div> 
                          <div class="return-method">
                            <div><input type="radio" value="auto"> Automatic Return</div>
                            <div><input type="radio" value="manual"> Manual Return</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                       </div>
                       <table class="get-license-confirm"> 
                        <tr>
                          <td><!--<a href="" class="btn btn-warning confirm-my-license">GET LICENSE</button>-->
                            <a href="#/my-licenses" class="btn btn-warning glicense">GET LICENSE</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>                    

                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div id="license" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <!--<img class="modal-cont" src="images/license-popup.png">-->
                    <div class="purchase-license">
                       <div class="license-heading">Get License</div> 

                       <table class="get-license-confirm"> 
                        <tr>
                          <td><!--<a href="" class="btn btn-warning confirm-my-license">GET LICENSE</button>-->
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning confirm-my-license">GET LICENSE</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>


                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


 <div id="confirm-license" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="purchase-license">
                       <div class="license-heading">Confirm</div> 
                       <table class="get-license-confirm"> 
                        <tr>
                          <td><a href="#/my-licenses" class="btn btn-warning buy">Confirm</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

code:

```
 $(".get-me-license").click(function(){
          $("#license").modal('show');
        });

         $(".get-me-license-tmp").click(function(){
          $("#license-temp").modal('show');
        });

         $(".buy").click(function(){
          $(".buy").modal('hide');
        });

       $(".confirm-my-license").click(function(){
          $("#confirm-license").modal('show');
          $('#license').modal('hide')
        });
```

After closing all popups it looks like below image...the backdrop still remains.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Ajai, sorry buddy... unfortunately there are lots of dependency on that code. so if i put a part of it. it might work.

Comment: @MithunRaikar: I have try to sol your problem in this post. please check it and let me know if its working fine.

Comment: @MithunRaikar : Its Pleasure. keep it up. Keep Coding. Have happy coding!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open modal then there is some style add in body and append div to body so you need to remove that style and that div.
Hi have solution for that.

```
$(".get-me-license").click(function(){
     $("#license").modal('show');
});

$(".get-me-license-tmp").click(function(){
     $("#license-temp").modal('show');
});

$(".buy").click(function(){
      $(".buy").modal('hide');
      $('body').removeClass().removeAttr('style');$('.modal-backdrop').remove(); // added by me
});

$(".confirm-my-license").click(function(){
     $("#confirm-license").modal('show');
     $('#license').modal('hide');
     $('body').removeClass().removeAttr('style');$('.modal-backdrop').remove(); // added by me
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This Code

```
$('body').removeClass().removeAttr('style');$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```